# C# UWP themes dynamically change

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, themes, uwp-xaml

I am trying to make my UWP (Windows 10) application to have option for dynamic theme change.

I have added a toggle button, that should toggle dark/light theme. But I have managed to change only on the current page, as soon as I navigate to other page the theme is returned to default one. The code goes like this:

```
RequestedTheme = toggleButton.IsChecked.Value ? ElementTheme.Light : ElementTheme.Dark;
```

Also, I would like to make my own light and dark theme.

Is there any easy solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to change the theme in real time, without restarting your app, you should change the theme of app's rootFrame. `((Frame)Window.Current.Content).RequestedTheme = toggleButton.IsChecked.Value ? ElementTheme.Light : ElementTheme.Dark;`

Comment: Thank you, this solved that. Just another question, how can I customize styles? For example, how to make custom colors for Dark style?

Comment: You have to create custom resource dictionaries for each theme. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#theme-resources-and-theme-dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>instead of changing the RequestTheme on the page object use the App.
App.Current.RequestTheme = toggleButton.IsChecked.Value ? ElementTheme.Light : ElementTheme.Dark;</strike>

see 
[Changing Theme in Windows 10 UWP App Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554871/changing-theme-in-windows-10-uwp-app-programmatically)

Comment: This isn't supported. `Application.RequestedTheme` can only be changed in the app constructor.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in ConceptProject.exe but was not handled in user code